# Execute FIND command with php

Tags: php

I am trying to execute the following command with PHP.

Any one have a better suggestion or and idea why it does not work?

Looking at the error log doesn't provide any useful info...

Command :

```
$pp = shell_exec(find /direcotry/*.jpg -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -l | gawk '{sum += $5; n++;} END {print \"Total Size: \" sum/1024/1024 \" MB : Avg Size: \" sum/n/1024 \" KB : Total Files: \" n ;}';
```

Log :

```
[Mon Jan 28 11:08:27 2013] [error] [client X.X.X.X] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VAR in /var/www/html/report/functions/avgSize.php on line 15
```

Comment: You forgot the starting quotes

Comment: `shell_exec` expects a string to be passed to it.

Comment: You should really use an editor with syntax highlighting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need quotes, and you forgot to close your call:

```
 $pp = shell_exec("find /direcotry/*.jpg -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -l | gawk '{sum += $5; n++;} END {print \"Total Size: \" sum/1024/1024 \" MB : Avg Size: \" sum/n/1024 \" KB : Total Files: \" n ;}");
```

Also make sure the user that executes the script has permission to run find.

Answer (score 1):

Put your find command into a file and chmod +x it.
Then call

```
$pp = shell_exec("/PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE/YOUR_FILE");
```

Comment: This is definitely a better idea than executing arbitrary code straight from PHP.  Much more readable and possibly more secure.

Comment: Looking better! Now php echos : 
    3009598.7625498

The shell echos : 
Total Size: 6777.15 MB : Avg Size: 2764.86 KB : Total Files: 2510


Thoughts on how I can get them to line up?